# Field input value is longer than screen field ABAP

Tags: abap

I have a little problem with a batch input. When running the BATCH INPUT since a program type ABAP I receive the next error:
**Field BKPF-BLART . input value is longer than screen field P**

```
PARAMETERS:
    p_bldat  TYPE CHAR10,   "Fecha de documento.
    p_budat  TYPE CHAR10,   "Fecha de contabilización.
    p_xblnr  TYPE XBLNR,    "Referencia.
    p_bktxt  TYPE BKTXT,    "Texto cabecera.
    p_blart  TYPE BLART,    "Clase.
    ...........

    PERFORM OPEN_GROUP.
     PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0100'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLDAT'  'p_bldat'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BUDAT'  'p_budat'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-XBLNR'  'p_xblnr'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BKTXT'  'p_bktxt'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLART'  'p_blart'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-MONAT'  'p_monat'.
     ......
```

I tried utilizing the sentence `CONDENSE` and changing the type of data `CHAR2` of my var `BLART`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing parameters as you think but character sequences that happen to be your parameter names.

It should be done like that (without quotes for parameter names).

```
PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLDAT'  p_bldat.
PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BUDAT'  p_budat.
PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-XBLNR'  p_xblnr.
PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BKTXT'  p_bktxt.
PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLART'  p_blart.
PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-MONAT'  p_monat.
```

Comment: Ready, this is the problem thanks. but Now I have only one problem with the field `PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-WRBTR'   p_wrbtr`.

Comment: Field BSEG-WRBTR . input value is longer than screen